# How to retrieve the optimization problem class

Tags: drake

Is there any way to show what class of optimization problem we have? E.g. SOCP, SDP, or totally nonconvex?

Or do we just need to try a bunch of solvers and see when they fail? Is SNOPT the only one that supports nonconvex optimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to [GetProgramType](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/namespacedrake_1_1solvers.html#acb5fa6010c00dad4d5867183f35a2f70) which returns if the program is LP, QP, SDP, etc.

> Is SNOPT the only one that supports nonconvex optimization?

No, we also have IPOPT and NLOpt for non-convex nonlinear optimization.

Answer (score 0):

> Or do we just need to try a bunch of solvers and see when they fail?

You can use [ChooseBestSolver](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.solvers.mathematicalprogram.html#pydrake.solvers.mathematicalprogram.ChooseBestSolver) to find the best-suited solver to the program.

```
from pydrake.solvers import mathematicalprogram as mp

# Make a program.
prog = mp.MathematicalProgram()
x = prog.NewContinuousVariables(2, "x")
prog.AddLinearConstraint(x[0] + x[1] == 0)
prog.AddLinearConstraint(2*x[0] - x[1] == 1)

# Find the best solver.
solver_id = mp.ChooseBestSolver(prog)
solver = mp.MakeSolver(solver_id)
assert solver.solver_id().name() == "Linear system"

# Solve.
result = solver.Solve(prog)
```

There is also a `mp.Solve` function that does all of that at once.

> Is SNOPT the only one that supports nonconvex optimization?

The [documentation](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/group__solvers.html) has the full list of solvers.  At the moment SNOPT, Ipopt, NLopt are the available non-linear solvers.